# How to mimic mongoose 'save' and 'validate' methods

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocking

I have this code

```
   var user = new User({ /** stuff **/ });   

  user.validate((err) => {
      if (err) {            
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid input' });
       }
       else {
           // save the sample user
            user.save((err) => {
                if (err) { throw err; }
                res.json({ success: true });
            });
       }
  });
```

I want to change `user` to my `mock user` so code above won't talk to the actual db. How can write custom `validate`, 'save' methods in such case?

My custom `user` mock `save` and `validate`:

```
public save(err:any) {
        return this;
    }

    public validate(err:any) {
        return this;
    }
```

But the execution just freezes then when I using my custom `user`. With `console.log()` I find out that my custom method `validate()` fired but execution is not continued after probably because missing `next()` but I have no idea how I can plug it in. Need help.